# angularJS question related to string combine

Tags: angularjs

I am learning AngularJS and trying to understand the $scope part, I was trying to do string combine by creating three variables(ng-model) and see how javascript works with angularJS. Say if I insist on creating three of the ng-model, how do I combine the two strings and put them together in the rstString? I tried to read the $scope elements and the data is there, so what did I miss? Thank you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
    <head>
        <title>angularJS for beginners</title>
        <script src="../angular-1.7.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h4>combine two string using strong expression</h4>
        <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
                First String &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;: <input type="text" ng-model="firstString" ng-init="firstString='hello '"/><br><br>

                Second String: <input ng-model="secondString" ng-init="secondString=' world'"/><br><br>
                
                Resulting String:<p style="color:blue;font-weight:bold;" ng-model="rstString" ng-init="rstString='aaa'"></p>
        </div>
        
    <script>
        var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
        app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
            console.log($scope);
            
            console.log("1st:"+$scope.firstString);
            console.log("2nd:"+$scope.secondString);
            console.log("rst:"+$scope.rstString);
            $scope.rstString = $scope.firstString +$scope.secondString;
        });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I added a button in your example :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
    <head>
        <title>angularJS for beginners</title>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.4-build.3588/angular.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h4>combine two string using strong expression</h4>
        <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
                First String &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;: <input type="text" ng-model="firstString" ng-init="firstString = 'hello '"/><br><br>

                Second String: <input ng-model="secondString" ng-init="secondString=' world'"/><br><br>
                
                Resulting String:<p style="color:blue;font-weight:bold;" ng-model="rstString" ng-init="rstString='aaa'">{{rstString}}</p>
            <button ng-click="concat()">Concat</button>
        </div>
        
    <script>
        var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
        app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {

            $scope.concat = function() {
            
                $scope.rstString = $scope.firstString +$scope.secondString;
            }
        });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

You can do like this too :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
    <head>
        <title>angularJS for beginners</title>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.4-build.3588/angular.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h4>combine two string using strong expression</h4>
        <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
                First String &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;: <input type="text" ng-model="firstString"/><br><br>

                Second String: <input ng-model="secondString"/><br><br>
                
                Resulting String:<p style="color:blue;font-weight:bold;" ng-model="rstString">{{rstString}}</p>
            <button ng-click="concat()">Concat</button>
        </div>
        
    <script>
        var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
        app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
            $scope.firstString = 'hello ';
            $scope.secondString = ' world ';
            $scope.rstString = 'aaa';

            $scope.concat = function() {
                $scope.rstString = $scope.firstString +$scope.secondString;
            }
        });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `ng-change` event

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
  <title>angularJS for beginners</title>
  <script src="../angular-1.7.9/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <h4>combine two string using strong expression</h4>
  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    First String &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;: <input type="text" ng-model="firstString" ng-init="firstString='hello '" ng-change="handleChange()"/><br><br>

    Second String: <input ng-model="secondString" ng-init="secondString=' world'" ng-change="handleChange()"/><br><br>
            
    Resulting String:<p style="color:blue;font-weight:bold;" ng-model="rstString" ng-init="rstString='aaa'"></p>
    </div>
    
<script>
    var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
    app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
        console.log($scope);
        
        console.log("1st:"+$scope.firstString);
        console.log("2nd:"+$scope.secondString);
        console.log("rst:"+$scope.rstString);

        $scope.handleChange = () => {
           $scope.rstString = $scope.firstString +$scope.secondString;
        };
    });
    </script>
</body>
```